# Detecting ad slate in Dash Manifest from Exoplayer in Android

Tags: android, video-streaming, exoplayer, live-video

I am developing a solution to detect ad slate in live content over SSAI.

So far we have been able to detect the ad slate in HLSManifest.

However I don't see any relevant object or information when it comes for DashManifest.

I see `EventStream` which is responsible for ad display

I am using the `onTimelineChanged` to read the manifest changes

```
override fun onTimelineChanged(timeline: Timeline, reason: Int) { 
    super.onTimelineChanged(timeline, reason)
 val manifest: Any? = exoPlayer.currentManifest 
   if (manifest is HlsManifest) readHLSManifest(manifest) 
   else if (manifest is DashManifest) readDASHManifest(manifest) 
}
```

Not able to figure what I can use for ad slate detection from Dash.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Too late on for the question, however for anyone stumbling onto it:
You have rightly said that it would need `EventStream`. An example would be:

```
<EventStream
 schemeIdUri="urn:scte:scte35:2013:bin"
 timescale="1">
 <Event
 presentationTime="1525119000"
 duration="60"
 id="55"
 messageData="/DAhAAAAAAAAAP/wEAUAAAA3f+9/fgBSZcAAAAAAAAAmObEZ"/>
</EventStream>
```

Where `messageData` is base64 encoded msg.

Reference from [this](https://www.unified-streaming.com/blog/how-do-scte-35-based-dynamic-ad-insertion-live-streaming-unified-origin) article.